# What is there to gain when helping people with bosses?

Tags: elden-ring

In Elden Ring, there is always people seemingly ready to help right before a boss.

The playthroughs I look at never get to the point where they try that mechanic. But from what I understood, it's not always people that also are at that point in the story and need help for the boss.

So I don't really understand: is there anything to gain by rerunning bosses as a helper to someone that needs the help?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There are a couple of incentives to helping the Host of Fingers defeat the area boss.

1. You gain a portion of the runes acquired when the boss is defeated. This amount appears to be **about 1/4th** of the number of runes the Host of Fingers gets. For example, if you help someone defeat [Margit, The Fell Omen](https://eldenring.wiki.fextralife.com/Margit,+the+Fell+Omen) in Stormveil Castle on a non-NG+ run, you'll receive around 3,750 runes (or 1/4th of 15,000).
2. You also gain a [Rune Arc](https://eldenring.wiki.fextralife.com/Rune+Arc). This is the typical multiplayer-related reward when a summoned player (ally or adversary) completes their goal.

Additionally, while not an explicit *benefit*, the helpers may also get a sense of accomplishment by helping out struggling players, if the monetary rewards aren't enough to incentivize them.

Comment: The accomplishment our new lord "Let Me Solo Her" must feel... ;)

Comment: I was *very strongly* resisting the urge to refer to that player in this answer. What an absolute legend.

Comment: @nightsurfer Praise "Let Me Solo Her"

Comment: For those out of the loop/don't know what we're talking about: https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/let-me-solo-her

Answer (score 6):

In addition to what was said by the other answer, helping with bosses is the only way to replay a boss fight in the same playthrough.

As an example, I never went to

> Murkwater Caves

prior to fighting Margit, which means that I never obtained

> Margit's shackle

prior to the fight. The only way I can replay the Margit fight with the item was to put down my summon sign in front of the fog wall.

Likewise, some of the other boss fights are fun, and the only way to replay them without going to NG+ is to act as a summon.